# Commandlet not displaying the output

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am facing a weird problem. When I run the following script, I do not get output for the `Get-Child` commandlet.

```
#Check status of Service Applications.
Write-Output -InputObject "SharePoint Service Application Status -"
Get-SPServiceApplication | select DisplayName,Status

Write-Output -InputObject "SharePoint Logfile Check -"
$logFilter = "WIN-RRAS-" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "*.log"
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS" -Filter $logFilter
```

When I run the last commandlet (`Get-ChildItem`) separately in a new ISE window, it is displaying the correct output.

The output which I get of above code is -

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Checklist.ps1
SharePoint Service Application Status -

DisplayName                                                 Status
-----------                                                 ------
Access Services 2010                                        Online
Secure Store Service                                        Online
PowerPoint Conversion Service Application                   Online
State Service                                               Online
Workflow Service Application                                Online
Project Server Service Application                          Online
PerformancePoint Service Application                        Online
Visio Graphics Service                                      Online
Managed Metadata Service                                    Online
App Management Service                                      Online
Security Token Service Application                          Online
Machine Translation Service                                 Online
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application Online
Usage and Health data collection                            Online
Search Administration Web Service for Hello Search!         Online
Word Automation Services                                    Online
User Profile Service                                        Online
Business Data Connectivity Service                          Online
Access Services                                             Online
Hello Search!                                               Online
SharePoint Logfile Check -















PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a variable that is not set properly. If it's working in a new seperate ISE, it would indicate that some of the variables used in the one you're currently used, is not updated or cleared.

I cannot see any variables used, that would give the weird error. So perhaps you played around with some environment variables/settings?

When i encounter issues like this, i usually restart my ISE and reload the script.
See if that helps?

Comment: Tried reloading ISE. Did not work. I haven't modified any environment variables/settings. I am trying to run this on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Comment: How is the permissions of that folder? Can you do a regular Get-childitem on it, without the filter option? Like so:
    Get-Childitem -path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS'

Comment: That command works perfectly fine :) 
If i assign the output of `Get-SPServiceApplication` to a variable and then echo that variable, it works fine.

Comment: I'm confused wether the problem is now solved or not. If it is not, the logfilter just caught my eye.
"WIN-RRAS-" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "*.log"
What is the meaning of "\*.log" - instead of just ".log" ? It's the extension of the file you're trying to make sure is .log - right?

Comment: If so, you can leave out that part, and on your get-content append an additional parameter; -file. like so:
get-childitem C:\ -File "*.log"

Answer (score 0):

You **are** getting output (see all those lines where the objects don't have a "DisplayName" nor a "Status")?

The problem is that you've specifically told PowerShell which columns to show (i.e. `Select DisplayName, Status`), but then the second set of objects doesn't have the same properties, so those columns are just blank.

If you just want to output both sets of objects *to the screen*, you can use `| Out-Default` after each one:

```
#Check status of Service Applications.
Write-Output -InputObject "SharePoint Service Application Status -"
Get-SPServiceApplication | select DisplayName, Status | Out-Default

Write-Output -InputObject "SharePoint Logfile Check -"
$logFilter = "WIN-RRAS-" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "*.log"
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS" -Filter $logFilter | Out-Default
```

Anyway, the point is that it's *purely a **display** problem.* You could also just not use a Select statement -- by default PowerShell would switch to list format when the second set of objects don't have the same properties.

The objects are being output, but in a table where they have nothing to show.

A better option might be to change properties of the output objects so they have (some of) the same names:

```
#Check status of Service Applications.
Write-Output -InputObject "SharePoint Service Application Status -"
Get-SPServiceApplication |
    Select @{Label="Name"; Expr={$_.DisplayName}}, 
           @{Label="Last"; Expr={$_.Status}}

Write-Output -InputObject "SharePoint Logfile Check -"
$logFilter = "WIN-RRAS-" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "*.log"
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS" -Filter $logFilter | 
    Select Name, @{ Label="Last"; Expr={$_.LastWriteTime}}, Length, FullName
```